# How to locate a button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Below is the source code for two buttons:

```
 <div class="picker__footer">
    <button class="picker__button--clear" type="button" data-pick="1411929000000" aria-controls="start-date"> :: before "Today" </button>
    <button class="picker__button--clear" type="button" data-clear="1" aria-controls="start-date"> :: before "Close" </button>
 </div>
```

I want to click on second button without using Xpath, actually I want to use only any one of these locators (http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy). Is it possible to handle these types of element without Xpath in protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
element(by.css('button[data-clear]')).click();
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify the value of `data-clear` attribute . I am expecting to work it as `element(by.css('button[data-clear=1]')).click();`. So that if two webelements have same attribute then I can make css unique by specifying the value of same attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to grab the partial button text, thusly...

```
element(by.partialButtonText('Close')).click();
```

Or get all the buttons and using an index, click the 2nd one...

```
$$('.picker__button--clear').get(1).click();
```

You should not need to use XPath at all.

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention the position of the button if there were duplicates.

syntax :  `driver.(byxpath("(//*['id=xxxxx'][position()=2]")).click();`

Comment: Thanks Dollar, but I have already mentioned in my question that I do not want to use xpath at all.

Answer (score 0):

One more way.

`element.all(by.css('.picker__button--clear')).last()`